# jQuery: Multiple close options for div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little trouble getting this work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

When the user clicks the X the div should close, but it also closes when they click outside of the wrapper container.

I can't seem to get them both to work. The X currently isn't closing anything.

jsFiddle(sorry it's not the cleanest, but it has the HTML): https://jsfiddle.net/t0mr4psf/1/

Gif for it in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEZyz.jpg

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a.open-answer').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.wrapper').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('.wrapper').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.question-container .wrapper:not(.active)').on('click', function(event) {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('a.open-answer', $(this)).click();
            return false;
        } 
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
       $('.wrapper').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.wrapper').click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your `html`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you include the HTML that this JQuery interacts with? Do you have a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @vince Added the link in the original post.

Comment: @Twisty Added, link.

Comment: @Bear I can't make heads or tails of what this should be doing. What am I looking at?

Comment: Need to see CSS too to understand this better. Please update jsfiddle.

Comment: Forked and working on it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mqj1fnn6/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer for you, but it's still not clear based on your description and image. Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mqj1fnn6/6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area container-fluid">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="no-gutters why-school-qa">
                <div id="question1" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div id="q-1" class="question">
                            <div id="qa-image-1" class="qaimage">
                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">Header</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">This is a Question</h3>
                            <div id="a-1" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-1" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-2" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div class="question">
                            <div class="qaimage">
                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">Another Header</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">Oh look, another question?</h3>
                            <div id="a-2" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                    <br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-blue" href="http://www.fodors.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-2" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-3" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div class="question">
                            <div class="qaimage">
                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">Sweet Header!</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">Questions with answers and stuff?</h3>
                            <div id="a-3" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-blue" href="http://lipmanhearne.com">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-3" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-4" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div class="question">
                            <div class="qaimage">
                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">Header and more HEADERS!</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">Questions?!</h3>
                            <div id="a-4" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-4" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-5" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div class="question">
                            <div class="qaimage">
                                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">Hmmmm?</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">Ok, got it. Makes sense</h3>
                            <div id="a-5" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-5" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-6" class="question-container">
                    <div class="wrapper has-media">
                        <div class="question">
                            <div class="qavideo">
                                <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zVXnoIoWu88?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="qaheader">I am the header now!</h4>
                            <h3 class="qaquestion">I'm questioning the question</h3>
                            <div id="a-6" class="answer">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">This is a link</a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#a-6" class="icon open-answer"><i class="ti-plus">+</i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <!-- #main -->
    </div>
    <!-- #primary -->
</div>
<!-- #content -->
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.open-answer').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var self = $(this);
        var isOpen = (self.text() == "x");
        $("a.open").not(self).click();
        if(!isOpen){
            self.text("x").addClass("open");
            $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("open");
        } else {
            self.text("+").removeClass("open");
            $($(this).attr("href")).removeClass("open");
        }
        $(self.attr("href")).toggle();
    });

    $('.question-container .wrapper').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a.open-answer', $(this)).click();
    });

    $(this).click(function () {
        $('a.open').click();
    });

    $('.wrapper').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Giving each Question and Answer their own unique ID can be helpful for selection. The Classes can be helpful in dealing with groups or when trying to select an unknown target.

Basically doing a manual toggle here. First we capture details about the item that was clicked in `self` and `isOpen`. Next, we close any other items that are `.open`. Then we return to `self` and open it.